# netbeans database connectivity

Tags: javascript, java, netbeans-8

i have made program for database connectivity but it is giving me the error kindly help.
here is a code

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)t1.getModel();
String query="SELECT * FROM emp";
try
{
    Class.forName("java.sql.Driver").newInstance();
    String DB="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopping";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB,"root","mysql");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next())
    {
        int e= rs.getInt("Empno");
        String n=rs.getString("Empname");
        String j= rs.getString("Job");
        String d= rs.getString("Hiredate");
        String s= rs.getString("Sal");
        String D= rs.getString("Deptno");
        Object rec[]={e,n,j,d,s,D};
        model.addRow(rec);
    }          
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
}    
catch (Exception e)
{
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in connectivity"); 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                  

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
```

Comment: What in the world is the error (Exception) you are getting?

Comment: public static void main(String args[]) {                                                         
in output :Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of expression
 at NewJFrame.b1ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:124)

Comment: can you come on teamviewer to explain it

Answer (score 0):

Change your Class.forName() method to:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

This loads the driver for mysql but you must have attached the library to your project.